# change c# form application width in left direction

Tags: c#, winforms

So I wanted to change my form size on a button click and also wanted it to look like a little animation so this code help me

```
while (desiredWidht < this.Width)
{
    this.Width += 5;                    
    Thread.Sleep(4);
}
```

but there is one problem. this code expands form in right direction. how can I do the same thing in left direction.. I tried expanding the form then moving it left and moving all controls to the right but the problem was that after form reached certain width controls disappeared for some reason and when the expansion method was done they appeared back again. I cannot figure out what is the problem. What is the proper way I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
this.Refresh();
```

after moving the controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int MAX_STEP = 5;

while (Width < desiredWidth)
{
    int step = Math.Min(MAX_STEP, desiredWidth - Width);
    SetBounds(Left - step, Top, Width + step, Height);
    Refresh();
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(4);
}
```

Here I've done a couple of things, first was defining a maximum step and setting the step so you'll get the exact width you desire. The big change here from the over answer was the SetBounds which will set all the properties atomically, I didn't have anything else going on in my sample program so I was seeing the right side gitter back and form as I was setting the width then the left (previously when testing a solution). You probably have this in some other process so you'll need to raise the event Application.DoEvents() and like mentioned by @banana you can do a Refresh(), that should be automatically called but it shouldn't hurt calling it again.
Also, I spelled Width correctly in desiredWidth, it was driving me crazy!
The "this.Property" or "this.Method" is a redundant qualifier of "this" so I've removed it from my example.

**Note, look into ClientSize.Width as it is typically what people want, you may want to also look to SetDesktopBounds